# Removing rows from R data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, rows

I have the following data frame:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   3149 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ mkod : int  5029 5035 5036 5042 5048 5050 5065 5071 5072 5075 ...
 $ mad  : Factor w/ 65 levels "Akgün Kasetçilik         ",..: 58 29 59 40 56 11 33 34 19 20 ...
 $ yad  : Factor w/ 44 levels "BAKUGAN","BARBIE",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ donem: int  201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 ...
 $ sayi : int  201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 201101 ...
 $ plan : int  2 2 3 2 2 2 7 3 2 7 ...
 $ sevk : int  2 2 3 2 2 2 6 3 2 7 ...
 $ iade : int  0 0 3 1 2 2 6 2 2 3 ...
 $ satis: int  2 2 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 4 ...
```

I want to remove 21 specific rows from this data frame.

```
> a <- df[df$plan==0 & df$sevk==0,]
> nrow(a)
[1] 21
```

So when I remove those 21 rows, I will have a new data frame with 3149 - 21 = 3128 rows. I found the following solution:

```
> b <- df[df$plan!=0 | df$sevk!=0,]
> nrow(b)
[1] 3128
```

My above solution uses a modified logical expression (`!=` instead of `==` and `|` instead of `&`). Other than modifying the original logical expression, how can I obtain the new data frame without those 21 rows? I need something like that:

```
> df[-a,] #does not work
```

**EDIT** (especially for the downvoters, I hope they understand why I need an alternative solution): I asked for a different solution because I'm writing a long code, and there are various variable assignments (like `a`'s in my example) in various parts of my code. So, when I need to remove rows in advancing parts of my code, I don't want to go back and try to write the inverse of the logical expressions inside `a`-like expressions. That's why `df[-a,]` is more usable for me.

Comment: -1 You have a solution contained within the question.  There is no problem to solve (as the question is currently worded).

Comment: @RichieCotton: My solution uses a modified (different) logical expression which ends up with the result I need; but what I want to see is how to remove specific rows from a data frame. I included my solution in my question because I didn't want to see it in the answers.

Comment: I've added a few lines to my question to explain what I want to know.

Comment: I think there is confusion over why you want something like `df[-a,]`, when `df[df$plan!=0 | df$sevk!=0,]` seems to be the correct approach. Could you comment why, in the bigger picture, something like `df[-a,]` is preferable? Perhaps, in the bigger picture, there is an approach which avoids this problem.

Comment: It's because I'm writing a long code, and there are various variable assignments (like `a`'s in my example) in various parts of my code. So, when I need to remove rows in advancing parts of my code, I don't want to go back and try to write the inverse of the logical expressions inside `a`-like expressions. That's why `df[-a,]` is more usable for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `rownames` to specify a "complementary" dataframe. Its easier if they are numerical rownames:

```
df[-as.numeric(rownames(a)),]
```

But more generally you can use:

```
df[setdiff(rownames(df),rownames(a)),]
```

Comment: Of course this assumes you have rownames, which the OP did in this case, but it's not a general solution

Answer (score 15):

Just negate your logical subscript:

```
a <- df[!(df$plan==0 & df$sevk==0),]
```

Answer (score 9):

Are you looking for `subset()`?

```
dat <- airquality
dat.sub <- subset(dat, Temp > 80 & Month < 10)

dim(dat)
dim(dat.sub)
```

Applied to your example:

```
df.sub <- subset(df, plan != 0 & sevk != 0)
```

Comment: This is the same as my solution: `df[df$plan!=0 | df$sevk!=0,]` which selects a subset; but thanks anyway.

Comment: BTW, the `&` operator must be `|` (OR) operator in `subset(df, plan != 0 & sevk != 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. 'a' needs to be a vector of indices:

```
    df <- data.frame(plan=runif(10),sevk=runif(10))
    a <- c(df$plan<.1 | df$sevk < .1) # some logical thing
    df[-a,]
```

or, with your data:

```
    a <- c(df$plan==0 & df$sevk==0)
    df[-a,]
```

Comment: I tried the last two lines of your code with my data, but it gives the wrong result (3148 rows instead of 3128). (BTW, `b[-a,]` should be `df[-a,]` I guess)

Comment: sorry about the slop- it works with my self-contained little example above, so I guess whatever is going on with your data is over my head

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you object to your solution, but here's another  way.

```
which( df[df$plan==0 & df$sevk==0,], arr.ind=TRUE) ->killlist 
newdf <- df[-c(killlist[1,])]
```